# Copy text from one textbox to other in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, readfile

I have a text file of 1MB. I have created a textbox and wrote 1MB of file in that textbox. Now I need to copy only 256 bytes of text data from the textbox(that contains 1MB of text information) and copy it into another textbox.
Once 256 bytes of text is copied, the next 256 bytes of text should be copied, until all the data is copied from 1 textbox to another.

Comment: Ok, that can be done. Add you code as [mcve] and explain the problem you are facing. Your question does not have any questions.

Comment: Why you shouldn't simple assign the text like `TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text`?

Comment: You need show what code you've attempted and which part isn't working!?

Comment: OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog;  OpenFileDialog.Filter = "Text files(*.doc)|*.txt|Allfiles(*.*)|*.*"; if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)   {    textbox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName;

Comment: the above code is for reading a text file from a document and putting it into textbox. Now I need to copy every 256 bytes of data to other textbox, until complete text is copied  to other textbox

Answer (score 0):

So I don't understand why you need to cope the string in 256 byte packages, but as a  general approach you can try something like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var largeStringOfOneMB = "Hello World";
    var largeStringOfOneMBAsByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(largeStringOfOneMB);
    var largeStringOfOneMBAsStream = new MemoryStream(largeStringOfOneMBAsByteArray);
    var newByteArray = new byte[256];

    for (int i = 0; i <= largeStringOfOneMBAsByteArray.Length / 256; i++)
    {
        largeStringOfOneMBAsStream.Read(newByteArray, i * 256, 256);
        var newStringWith256BytesOfTheOriginalString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newByteArray);
        // Do what ever you have to
    }
}
```

First of all read your data from the file, convert it to a stream and read the packages. Then you can do what ever you have to with this package.